# Express not rendering my React Front End?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I have two repos for the Front End and Back End portions of my project.

The Front End is a simple create-react-app project that hits my Express Back End and received responses from API calls.

I ran `npm run build` in my Front End project and moved that build folder to the root of my express backend repo.

However, when I try to reach the root page (i.e. localhost:3001), for some reason the response only returns the static html from index.html and doesn't actually render anything.

But if I go to something that has a path like `localhost:3001/pokedex/1` then at least I see a correct response coming from the API.

I have a feeling that there is something wrong with the way I'm declaring my paths.

Here is the code on the Front End that is reaching out to the Back End:

```
import axios from 'axios'
const baseUrl = '/'

const getAll = () => {
    const request = axios.get(baseUrl)
    return request.then(response => response.data)
}

const getPkm = (id) => {
    const request = axios.get(`${baseUrl}pokedex/${id}`)
    return request.then(response => response.data)
}

export default { getAll, getPkm }
```

This is my Express Back End entry index.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')
const axios = require('axios')

//Middleware
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.static('build'))

const unknownEndpoint = (request, response) => {
    response.status(404).send({ error: 'unknown endpoint' })
}

let fullPkmList = require('./fullPkmList.json')

function ignoreFavicon(req, res, next) {
    if (req.originalUrl.includes('favicon.ico')) {
      res.status(204).end()
    }
    next();
  }

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=100`)
        .then((list) => res.json(list.data.results))
})

app.get('/pokedex/:id', (request, response) => {
    const id = Number(request.params.id)
    const pokemon = fullPkmList[id - 1]

    if (pokemon) {
        axios.all([
            axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}`),
            axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/${id}`)
        ])
            .then(axios.spread((pokemonResponse, speciesReponse) => {
                let pkmResponse = pokemonResponse.data
                let speciesResponse = speciesReponse.data

                response.json({pkm: pkmResponse, species: speciesResponse })
            }))

    } else {
        response.status(404).end()
    }

})

app.use(unknownEndpoint)

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`this is a test ${PORT}`)
})
```

Code for the Front End: https://github.com/rohithpalagiri/pocketdex

Code for the Back End: https://github.com/rohithpalagiri/pocketdex-backend

To see the issue, you only need to run the backend. I console log the response and in that, you will see the index.html file markup being returned. My goal is to have all of the paths relative so that the root url doesn't really matter. I think that is the part I'm getting stuck on.

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: *"the response only returns the static html from index.html"* - that's what it's *supposed* to do. Did you look in the network tab or console to see why that isn't then loading the JS?

Comment: Are you trying to server side render the page? I saw you were using create react app, have you looked at this: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html

Comment: So that's the part that's a bit confusing to me. When I look in the network tab, I do see the chunk.js files being loaded along with all of the other assets.

Comment: @GrantHerman This is all new to me so still trying to wrap my head around the concepts. Apologies but I'll try and articulate it as best as I can.

At the moment I'm not, really all I'm trying to do is figure out why the JS that's being loaded is not rendering in the browser. My understanding is that when you hit the root of a page, it will call app.get('/') and start rendering the react code that's downloaded.

For example, when I hit something like localhost:3001/pokedex/1 all it returns is the JSON rather than any sort of markup.

Comment: *"I do see the chunk.js files being loaded"* - do those requests succeed? With the expected content? What does the console say, any errors?

Comment: Yeah that is what is supposed to happen based on what your showing for your express server. Have you ran npm start in your frontend code and go to `localhost:3000` ? What shows up on your frontnend app. To answer my own question it doesent look like your SSR, but are just simply having a frontend call your express server for data.

Comment: @GrantHerman When I load up my frontend project I receive a console error for a map function. I think we're on the right track:

I have a function in my useffect that runs on the root url (in this case localhost:3000) that is supposed to grab the response from app.get(''/') and map over it and set some states.

However, it's gonna return an error since the response from app.get('/") returns the index.html rather than the API call that you see above.

So this must be the issue, now the question is what's the best way to solve this? Is it not possible to make API requests at the root url?

Comment: @jonrsharpe They do but I think I found the issue. There's a console error because I'm trying to map over the response which I expect to be some JSON I receive from an API call in app.get('/') but instead since the response is the markup of index.html I get an error.

There's a conflict here that I'm not sure how to resolve. I'd like to make an API call when I hit my homepage and return that data as a response to the front end, but it looks like index.html is overriding it or I'm doing something wrong here.

Comment: Well how exactly did you expect Express to determine that when you requested / you expected the index.html but then when you requested / you expected an array? This is why API endpoints are generally put under a top-level route e.g. /api, so they don't interfere with the client routes. Look at e.g. https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/wiki/Architecture for an implementation I put together.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you very much I really appreciate your help.